# Cleaning redundant chronological team data in R

Tags: r, data-cleaning

I have a dataset ("dat") that looks something like this:

```
Team     Person1    Person2     Person3     Person4     Person5     Person6     Person7     Person8
1195880  37506459   37470284    NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA
6592553  30113892   33080542    21537647    32294183    NA          NA          NA          NA
6593701  697917     22860611    NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA
9595288  24433487   32370872    11522125    363290      8877040     22313302    32432767    NA
1595882  12318169   25645992    NA          NA          NA          NA          NA          NA
6595978  24433487   32370872    11522125    363290      8877040     22313302    32432767    NA
7545798  24433487   32370872    11522125    363290      8877040     22313302    NA          NA
2095820  12318169   25645992    37506459
```

dat is in chronological order.  Starting from the beginning of the dataset (i.e., the earliest point in time), I want to eliminate instances where either: a) the exact same group of people formed a team at a later point in time AND/OR b) a subset of a previously-formed team came together.  In both circumstances, I want to retain the earlier grouping and eliminate the more recent grouping.

For instance, in my example dataset teams 6595978 and 7545798 should both be eliminated; team 6595978 is an exact replica of team 9595288 (which was listed earlier chronologically) and team 7545798 is a subset of team 9595288.  However, team 2095820 should not be eliminated; although team 2095820 contains all of the members of the previously-listed team 1595882, team 2095820 should be retained because of the addition of a new member, person 37506459.

Any/all suggestions are welcome.  Thanks in advance!

Sincerely,
Amy

Answer (score 1):

How many rows do you have? This is a fairly inefficient way to solve the problem but if your data is of reasonable size it may work.

```
bad<-numeric();
for(i in 2:nrow(dd)) {
    for(j in 1:(i-1)) {
        if (all(dd[i,-1] %in% dd[j, -1])) {
            bad <- c(bad, i)
            break;
        }
    }
}
dd[bad, ]
#      Team  Person1  Person2  Person3 Person4 Person5  Person6  Person7 Person8
# 6 6595978 24433487 32370872 11522125  363290 8877040 22313302 32432767      NA
# 7 7545798 24433487 32370872 11522125  363290 8877040 22313302       NA      NA
```

Here's another idea using the `reshape2` library. Here we want to make sure that the Team column is a factor with the order given by the rows rather than sorted numerically/alphabetically.

```
dd$Team<-factor(dd$Team, levels=unique(dd$Team))

library(reshape2)
mm<-acast(melt(dd, "Team", na.rm=T), Team~value, length)
bad<-combn(1:nrow(mm), 2, function(z) {
    sum(mm[z[1],] == 1 & mm[z[1],] == mm[z[2],]) == sum(mm[z[2],]==1)
})
bad<-unique(combn(1:nrow(mm), 2)[2, bad])
levels(dd$Team)[bad]
# [1] "6595978" "7545798"
```

Comment: (+1) for the `combn` method. I was starting with `lapply(combn(nrow(dat), 2, simplify = FALSE), function(x) dat[x,])` and trying the comparisons that way and using `duplicated` across the columns

Comment: @RichardScriven Yeah, `combn` has it's own function= argument you can use rather than wrapping in an `lapply` which is kind of nice.

Comment: @MrFlick Thank you for the suggestions!  I tried both.  The first suggestion is still running (probably because I have over 80,000 rows in my dataset).  As for the second suggestion,  when I enter `mm<-acast(melt(dd, "Team", na.rm=T), Team~value, length)` I get the following error message: `Error: n must be a positive integer
In addition: Warning message:
In split_indices(.group, .n) : NAs introduced by coercion`

Comment: @waxattax I cannot replicate the error you are getting with the sample data so i'm not sure if it's just a matter of size or what. How often does a person appear on more than one team? You could reduce the size of your problem by first subsetting to rows with individuals appearing once. If that number is meaningfully less than 80,000, that will greatly reduce the computation time because these suggestions are both roughly `O(n^2)`